# move folder on a linux partition

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, partitioning

my os is CentOS 6 running as a virtual machine under ESX. I don't know why **/home** folder is mapped to the biggest partition. I want my own folder **/data** (which is next to /etc, /root, /home and others) to be 1.2T big.
How can I achieve this?

```
centos6 ~ # df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6-lv_root
                       50G  4.2G   43G   9% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   52M  408M  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6-lv_home
                      1.2T  199M  1.2T   1% /home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another logical volume (lv) and then steal space from lv_home and give it to lv_data (or whatever you call it). But that is going to involve a good amount of work to make sure that nothing in the partition on lv_home is using that space (work I'm not rightly sure how to perform offhand).

It might be easier to simply change your mount points if you really don't care about /home and aren't going to care in the future. This would involve actually creating a /home directory on the / filesystem (on lv_root) then moving all of /home to there. After which you can mount the partition on lv_home to /data (once you've moved all your data to there from the current /data.

If this is a new system you might be better off just reinstalling from scratch and getting the partitioning and layout correct in the installation wizard.

Alternatively you could just move the contents of /data to /home/data and then symlink or bind mount from /home/data to /data.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively copy your contents from /data/x to /home/x by doing

```
cp -Rp /data/x /home
```

After that change your login directory to be /home/x by using 'usermod' command.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep /data folder. I just want it to be much more bigger (1.2T) than it is now. I don't use /home folder and it should be as small as possible.